# Getting an errors after change the files name

Tags: c#, winforms

I getting an several errors after i change the files name. From default form name (Form2.cs), (Form1.cs) etc to the System.cs, LoginPage.cs and while i change back to the default form name (Form2.cs), this is what happens, the errors appears. What should i do? Is there any solution that i can back this problem to the time before i changed the files name?

[image]

This is the full code of "Form1.cs":

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace Sell_System
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string connectionString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\Archives\Projects\Program\Sell System\Sell System\App_Data\db1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label4.Visible = false;
            comboBox1.Items.Add("English");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Indonesian");
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

            OleDbDataReader dReader;
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT DISTINCT [Username] FROM [Member]", conn); 
            dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            AutoCompleteStringCollection namesCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

            while (dReader.Read())
            {
               namesCollection.Add(dReader.GetString(0));
            }

            textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection;

            dReader.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

            conn.Open();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Member] WHERE [Username]='" + textBox1.Text + "'AND [Password]='" + textBox2.Text + "'", conn);

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

            da.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                this.Hide();

                Form2 secondaryForm = new Form2(this);
                secondaryForm.ShowDialog();

                this.Close();
            }

            else if (textBox1.Text == "Admin" && textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                this.Hide();

                Form5 fifthForm = new Form5();
                fifthForm.ShowDialog();

                this.Close();
            }

            else
            {
                label4.Visible = true;

                if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "English")
                {
                    RecursiveClearTextBoxes(this.Controls);
                    label4.Text = "Invalid Username or Password!";
                    label4.ForeColor = Form1.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }

                else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Indonesian")
                {
                    RecursiveClearTextBoxes(this.Controls);
                    label4.Text = "Username atau Password anda salah!";
                    label4.ForeColor = Form1.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
            }

            conn.Close();
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "English")
            {
                ChangeLanguage("en");
            }

            else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Indonesian")
            {
                ChangeLanguage("id");
            }
        }

        private void ChangeLanguage(string language)
        {
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
                resources.ApplyResources(c, c.Name, new CultureInfo(language));
            }
        }

        private void RecursiveClearTextBoxes(Control.ControlCollection cc)
        {
            foreach (Control ctrl in cc)
            {
                TextBox tb = ctrl as TextBox;

                if (tb != null)
                {
                    tb.Clear();
                }

                else
                {
                    RecursiveClearTextBoxes(ctrl.Controls);
                }
            }
        }

        private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();

            Form3 thirdForm = new Form3();
            thirdForm.ShowDialog();

            this.Close();
        }

        protected virtual void ClosedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormsHandler.Remove(this);
        }

    }
}
```

The error on "Form1.cs" is:

**"Sell_System.Form1.cs" does not contain a definition for "Drawing"**

Comment: Show your full code.. And paste your errors as a text, not as an image..

Comment: You say you changed file names but in your screenshot errors are pointing to FormN.Designer files. You need to match those files names as well or at least names of partial classes contained inside.

Comment: @SonerGönül: please refer to the question above again. Thanks.

Comment: @Rafal: yeah, i already did, but when i changed the name, the error appear, so i thought that is happen because of i changed the name of the files, so i rename it again as default files name. But, the error still appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to take a look at the designer class (designer.cs), maybe the designer class is still referencing the old file name?